# PierfrancescoSoffritti Android Youtube Player Callback not working

Tags: android, kotlin, youtubeplayer

I am trying to implement the PierfrancescoSoffritti youtube Player but I am having issues the player callback OnReady never gets called

here is my code I don't know whats the issue here

```
  <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_youtube"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        app:showYouTubeButton="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

here is the XML

here is my kotlin implementation I am dynamically loading the video id to the player

```
viewModel.playYoutube.observe(this, EventObserver {

        with(binding.playerYoutube) {
            lifecycle.addObserver(this)
            isVisible = true
            addFullScreenListener(this@MyCourseActivity)
        }
        setYoutubePlayer(viewModel.youtubeUrl!!)
    })
}

private fun setYoutubePlayer(youtubeUrl: String) {
    if (::youtubePlayer.isInitialized) {
        val id = getYoutubeVideoId(youtubeUrl)
        youtubePlayer.loadVideo(id, 0f)
    }
    binding.playerYoutube.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {

        override fun onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, second: Float) {
            super.onCurrentSecond(youTubePlayer, second)
            Timber.d("onCurrentSecond %s ",second)
        }

        override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
            Timber.d("onReady called YouTube")
            youtubePlayer = youTubePlayer
            youtubePlayer.addListener(tracker)
            val id = getYoutubeVideoId(youtubeUrl)
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(id,  0f)
        }
    })

    Timber.d("tracker state %s",tracker.state)
    Timber.d("tracker state %s",tracker.currentSecond)
    Timber.d("tracker state %s",tracker.videoDuration)
    Timber.d("tracker state %s",tracker.videoId)
}
```

I am using kotlin and  androidX Dependencies
kindly guide me on why the player isn't working

the states which I am receiving are ->

```
tracker state UNKNOWN
tracker state 0.0
tracker state 0.0
tracker state null
```